# Check if a header contains a valid UUID

Tags: karate

I am trying to check if the header `Location` ends with a valid UUID. I've tried the following approach

```
Scenario: Create an airline
    Given path '/somePath'
    And request { some: 'request' }
    When method post
    Then status 201
    Then match header Location == '/somePath/#uuid'
```

I am thinking about creating a function for extracting the UUID and then just try `match extractedUUID == '#uuid'`

How can achieve this the most 'karate way'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the best option:

```
* def location = responseHeaders['Location'][0]
* def temp = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
* match temp == '#uuid'
```

Comment: Nice! I am going to create a function called `extractLastURLSegmentOfLocationHeader` (I am a verbose guy) and place it in a feature to be reused. It's a pitty I can not use it like this `* match extractLastURLSegmentOfLocationHeader(responseHeaders) == '#uuid'` Well.. I am going to reuse that UUID so I need to define it first.